# Cygwin gfortran program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to run a fortran program for extraction data from MODIS 8 daily Leaf Area Index LAI and Fraction of Photosynthetic Active Radiation FPAR. first I projected MODIS raw *.hdf file to *.dat file by using *.sh. Then reformat from *.dat to *.txt by using g++ and this stage is my final stage of data preparation, which is combining all the *.txt data to specific format *.direct and *.8daily throughout the year from start to end by using fortran code.

```
Program  read_8daily
Implicit None

integer ir,ic
integer nnr, nnc
character filename1*80,filename2*80, string*20, year*4, day*3
character hour*2, outfile*200, ch2*2, ch5*5, chim*2
integer rec,count,i,j,sta,im, iday, ihour,iyear,d
integer, dimension (300,300):: fpar0, lai0
real, dimension (300,300):: fpar, lai
  integer, dimension (300,300)::modis1, modis2      
integer startday,endday,starthour,endhour
  integer  rec_no


nnc = 328           ! For Red River Basin
nnr = 395


do iyear = 2010, 2010         ! Change year 

write(year,  '(i4.4)') iyear

  startday = 1                  ! change start date (if)         
endday   = 361                  ! change end date (if)

print *, 'EVALUATING from:', iyear, startday
print *, '.............To:', iyear, endday

print *, 'Reading modis data...'



OPEN (15, file='FPAR.'//year//'.8daily', 
 :       status='unknown')

OPEN (16, file='LAI.'//year//'.8daily', 
 :       status='unknown')

OPEN (25, file='FPAR.'//year//'.direct', 
 :           form = 'unformatted', access = 'direct',
 :       recl = 4*nnc*nnr, status='unknown')    

OPEN (26, file='LAI.'//year//'.direct', 
 :           form = 'unformatted', access = 'direct',
 :       recl = 4*nnc*nnr, status='unknown')    


print *,'Writing', '..modis.'//year//'.daily'

  rec_no = 0    !record number for every monthly data file

  do iday = startday, endday, 8    !8-day snow cover product

 write(day,  '(i3.3)')  iday

filename1= year//day//'.fpar.txt'
```

c   filename1='/home/maheswor/koshi/LAIFPAR/input/koshi_'
c     ://year//'_'//day//'_fpar.txt'

```
filename2= year//day//'.lai.txt'
```

c   filename2='/home/maheswor/koshi/LAIFPAR/input/koshi_'
c     ://year//'_'//day//'_lai.txt'

```
OPEN(7, file=filename1)
OPEN(8, file=filename2)

    read(7,*) ((modis1(ir, ic),ic=1,nnc), ir=1,nnr)
    read(8,*) ((modis2(ir, ic),ic=1,nnc), ir=1,nnr)

      rec_no = rec_no + 1
    print *, 'record number:', rec_no

    do ir = 1, nnr
       do ic=1, nnc
         fpar0(ir,ic) = modis1(ir,ic) 
          lai0(ir,ic) = modis2(ir,ic)              

         end do
    end do

      print *, 'begin writing'
```

50  format(1x, 300i10)
        do ir = 1 ,nnr
          write(15,50) (fpar0(ir,ic),ic=1,nnc)
          write(16,50) (lai0(ir,ic),ic=1,nnc)
        end do

```
   write(25,rec = rec_no)  ((fpar0(ir,ic),ic=1,nnc),ir=1,nnr)
   write(26,rec = rec_no)  ((lai0(ir,ic), ic=1,nnc),ir=1,nnr)

end do         !do iday = startday, enday 

close(7)
    close(8)
    close(25)
close(26)
close(15)
close(16)

end do   !do iyear

end program
```

I ran that script in cygwin. I encountered the following problem in the photo. Please check and help.
[gfortran run and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XAMB.png)

Comment: Here's the hint: nnc and nnr are bigger thsn 300.

Comment: Use the fortran tag for all Fortran questions to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

Values of index variables are larger than both array dimensions

```
integer, dimension (300,300):: fpar0, lai0

nnc = 328           ! For Red River Basin
nnr = 395
```

later you are using them in loops where this segmentation fault is happens

```
do ir = 1, nnr
   do ic=1, nnc
     fpar0(ir,ic) = modis1(ir,ic) 
      lai0(ir,ic) = modis2(ir,ic)              

     end do
end do
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: One question is should I have to change the array dimensions or should I change the data value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed array dimensions higher than input data. Then it work well. Thanks for help!